# Closing .aspx as a fancybox popup with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I have a javascript function that makes a popup and loads an .aspx page inside the popup.
Here is my code:

```
function moveEvent(doTheMove) {
        var selectedNotesList = getSelectedNoteIDs();
        if (doTheMove) {
            $.fancybox({
                'autoScale': false,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'height': 225,
                'width': 800,
                'href': 'Utilities/MoveFileTemplate.aspx?eventID=' + selectedNotesList +
                '&oldEventCaseFile=' + $('#hidCaseFile').val(),
                onComplete: function () {
                    $('#fancybox-overlay').unbind();
                },
                onClosed: function () {
                    $("#viewNotesGrid").flexReload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
            showMessage("No expenses are selected.");
    }
```

In my .aspx page I have 3 radio buttons, a DropDownList and 2 buttons. What I am trying to do is close the popup when the user clicks on the "cancel" button instead of having to press the "X" button in the top corner. (When the cancel button is pressed it has to mimic the "X" button so that the "onClosed:" can fire and reload my flexigrid)
 Any suggestions?

Comment: can you paste the link from where you are refraining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
var theBox;
...
function moveEvent(doTheMove) {
...
   theBox = $.fancybox({
      'autoScale': false,
      'type': 'iframe',
      'height': 225,
      'width': 800,
      'href': 'Utilities/MoveFileTemplate.aspx?eventID=' + selectedNotesList +
            '&oldEventCaseFile=' + $('#hidCaseFile').val(),
      onComplete: function () {
         $('#fancybox-overlay').unbind();
      },
      onClosed: function () {
         $("#viewNotesGrid").flexReload();
      }
   });
...
} //close the moveEvent function
```

then on the onclick of your cancel button call

```
window.parent.theBox.close();
```

EDIT(OP): it is actually: parent.$.fancybox.close();

Comment: just so that I dont get confused. window.parent.theBox.close(); as  c# in my code behind or as a string then call RegisterScriptManager(not sure what it is but I've seen it) ?

Comment: you can add that directly in your button `<asp:button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.parent.theBox.close();"></asp:button>`

Comment: |I will try it and let you know

Comment: I've tried the OnClientClick= but it doesn't seem to close the popup.

Comment: ... maybe the `theBox = ...` does not the thing I'm expecting, need to try later.

Comment: parent.$.fancybox.close();  this seems to work. But thank you very much. You got me on the right track with OnClientClick which I didn't know about

Answer (score 1):

client side

- window.close(); as javascript code in

EDIT:
Server side

- Page.RegisterStartupScript("anykey","window.close();");

Comment: You should so it in the client side, it's quicker. If you need to do some processing in the code behind then use the server side code.

Comment: i don't think `window.close()` will work as expected if you call it inside an iframe...

Comment: You can refresh the parent, it will close then.